# Wtfforms dynamic generation

Tags: python, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have two wtfforms

```
class SportStartForm(Form):
    ski = DateField(format='%d.%m.%Y')
    kitesurfing = DateField(format='%d.%m.%Y')
    windsurfing = DateField(format='%d.%m.%Y')
    surfing = DateField(format='%d.%m.%Y')


class UpdateUserForm(Form):
    sport_start_at = FormField(SportStartForm)
```

It works fine, but I want generate one of this form dynamically

```
class SportStartForm(Form):
    def __new__(cls, **kwargs):
       for s in SPORTS:
           setattr(cls, s, DateField(format='%d.%m.%Y'))
    return super(SportStartForm, cls).__new__(cls, **kwargs)
```

If I do so I get an exception on a form validation

```
for name, unbound_field in itertools.chain(fields, extra_fields):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I researched a several questions here with the tags about to wtfforms dynamic generation, but it didn't work for me. What I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the basic issue causing the error is that because you overrode `__new__` and then called the super constructor, you consequentially bypassed [`Form.__init__`](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/2.1/wtforms/form.py#L244) which passes a mapping of fields to [`BaseForm.__init__`](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/2.1/wtforms/form.py#L22).

**However** Even trying to conform this interface probably won't end up getting you what you want, not without a significant amount more work. The reason is that WTForms uses a metaclass on `Form` which inspects fields and caches the unbound fields list at a point *before* your class is instantiated, and input processing is done at instantiation time, which requires all fields to have been declared by that point.

---

Following the tips from the [Solving Specific Problems](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/2.1/specific_problems.html#dynamic-form-composition) page, you can more safely create a dynamic form using one of these approaches:

**1.** Presuming SPORTS does not change after application initialization, we can simply create a top-level class and set attributes on it

```
class SportStartForm(Form):
    pass

for s in SPORTS:
    setattr(SportStartForm, s, DateField(format='%d.%m.%Y'))
```

**2.** alternately, if SPORTS is something that can change and is dynamic due to some user rules, it can be done in-view just like in the above linked page, or as a factory:

```
def factory(sports):
    # This form class is created in a local scope, so a new class object
    # is made each time your factory is called
    class SportStartForm(Form):
        pass

    for s in sports:
        setattr(SportStartForm, s, DateField(format='%d.%m.%Y'))

    return SportStartForm
```

Usage of the factory model could then be something like:

```
def view(request):
    form_class = factory(['tennis', 'golf', 'windsurfing'])
    form = form_class(request.form)
    # etc, rest of view
```