# Dynamic WTForm field is not validated

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

If you [dynamically add a field to a WTForms form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859978/add-fields-dynamically-to-wtforms-form), the newly-added fields are not validated (even if you add validators).

For instance, in Flask:

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add():
    if 'state' not in session:
        session['state'] = 1

    form = MyForm()

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        if session['state'] == 1:
            setattr(
                MyForm,
                'asd',
                StringField(
                    'asdfield',
                    validators = [
                        DataRequired(),
                        Length(min=1)
                    ]
                )
            )
            form = MyForm()
            session['state'] = 2
            return render_template(
                'add.html',
                form=form
            )
        print(len(form.asd.data)) # can equal 0
        session['state'] = 1
        return redirect('/add')
    return render_template(
        'add.html',
        form=form
    )
```

I believe this is due to the fact that `form = MyForm()` is run every time you go to `/add`, so even if `session['state'] == 2` you run `form.validate()` on a default form which does not have the dynamically-added field. Therefore, this field cannot be part of the form validation process.

How can one properly address this behaviour ? If it's not possible, then how can one dynamically add fields to an existing form in such a way that all fields get properly validated upon submission ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you call `validate()` before adding the field, naturally, you can't validate a field which doesn't exist yet.  That said, you don't want to add a field to an **instance** instead of a **class**. This is because since WTForms processes its input data at construction, adding fields to the instance is mostly a meaningless thing.

If your field name is static, you can use the `del` trick detailed [here](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.1/specific_problems.html#removing-fields-per-instance)

If it's dynamic, you could instead follow the [dynamic form composition pattern](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.1/specific_problems.html?highlight=custom#dynamic-form-composition) from the docs.

Since I've gone over this in detail, I'll link my previous example here:
[Wtfforms dynamic generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373823/wtfforms-dynamic-generation/34580824#34580824)

Comment: I've actually done that beforehand and it did work, but I forgot to add a portion of code to show errors when `session['state']==2` (thus making me believe there was no validation). I should also mention that the dynamic field have to be removed using `delattr` otherwise they will stay forever.